# Do we need to disclose affiliation in every answer?

Tags: discussion

Since I've worked at PortSwigger support I've answered questions relating to Burp on here. Someone [commented](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172091/pentesting-web-applications-with-unique-strings-in-url/172100?noredirect=1#comment351170_172100) that affiliation should be declared. Doing this on every question seems a bit unnecessary to me but I will do if the community/mods say so.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have already done so with your username and logo, but the affiliation is not always clear (more brand recognition with Burp Suite than with PortSwigger).

If you are answering questions about a PortSwigger product, then I'd say that you are fine with your username and logo.

If you are suggesting that a PortSwigger product could be used as a solution to the question (thereby *promoting* the PortSwigger product), then a boilerplate disclaimer would be appreciated so that your natural bias is clear.

From my interactions with your answers, I don't think that you caused any problems or errors.

Comment: Agreed, and the affiliation is explicit in the user profile (which is the main requirement). It's a good differentiation, answering a question *about* Burp vs suggesting Burp as a solution in an answer to a non-Burp question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sounds good to me.

Comment: When you say a boiler plate disclaimer would be appreciated, does that apply to sort of obvious affiliations or all? I just noticed an answer where a user seemed to be promoting their product but I didn't see any obvious affiliation or a declared affiliation.

Comment: @Limit it all depends on "obvious"

Comment: Sorry, I should have used the word explicit instead of obvious.